# pyspark read hdfs file - no such file or directory error

Tags: pyspark, hdfs

I am using pyspark to process a text file in hdfs. If I use simple hdfs command like "hdfs dfs -cat hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt"; it works.

But if I use pyspark command like the following, it keeps return "[Errno 2] No such file or directory : "
[image]

```
schemaMismatches = StructType([
    StructField("song_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("song_artist", StringType(), True),
    StructField("song_title", StringType(), True),
    StructField("track_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("track_artist", StringType(), True),
    StructField("track_title", StringType(), True)
])

hdfs dfs -cat hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt
#hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt
hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt
with open("hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    sid_matches_manually_accepted = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("< ERROR: "):
            a = line[10:28]
            b = line[29:47]
            c, d = line[49:-1].split("  !=  ")
            e, f = c.split("  -  ")
            g, h = d.split("  -  ")
            sid_matches_manually_accepted.append((a, e, f, b, g, h))

matches_manually_accepted = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(sid_matches_manually_accepted, 8), schema=schemaMismatches)
matches_manually_accepted.cache()
matches_manually_accepted.show(10, 20)
```

I suppose the file path that I used for pyspark is wrong, but I am not sure how to fix that though.

Answer (score 0):

you should read that text file in “Spark way”, not normal Python way

```py
df = spark.read.text('hdfs:///data/msd/tasteprofile/mismatches/sid_matches_manually_accepted.txt')

df.show()
```